# Restlet getRequest is always null on a Resource

Tags: rest, restlet

I have the following

```
    public synchronized Restlet createRoot() {
    Router router = new Router(getContext());
    router.attach("/search/{query}", SearchResource.class);
    return router;
}
```

So `query` is the search query (variable)

I am trying to get this variable from my resource but I am always returned null.

```
public SearchResource() {
    searchQuery = (String) getRequestAttributes().get("query");
}
```

I am getting a null pointer at `getRequestAttributes()` or if I try `getRequest().getAttributes()`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me :

```
public class SearchResource extends ServerResource {

        @Get
    public YourBean getYourBean() {
           String searchQuery = (String) getRequest().getAttributes().get("searchQuery");
           .....
       }
}
```